# How to send a Notification to multiple Registration IDs and recieve them using GCM?

Tags: android, push-notification, google-cloud-messaging

I implemented a PHP code to send a notification to multiple Registration IDs but after searching alot, i didn't find an implementation to GCMIntentService & GCMBroadcastReciever that can show me how to implement it on my code
Here is the PHP code

```
$url = 'https://android.googleapis.com/gcm/send';

$fields = array(
        'registration_ids'  => $apiKey,
        //'data'              => array( "message" => $message ),
        'data'  =>$message ,
);

$headers = array(
        'Authorization: key=' . "AIzaSyBCzOGxXyvvo8-ZSzesOsTIYa-7Ua64_SM",
        'Content-Type: application/json'
);

// Open connection
$ch = curl_init();

// Set the url, number of POST vars, POST data
curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url );

curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_POST, true );
curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true );

curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, json_encode( $fields ) );

// Execute post
$result = curl_exec($ch);

// Close connection
curl_close($ch);

echo $result;
}
```

AND here is my Android class that i implemented

```
package guc.edu.iremote;

import android.app.Notification;
import android.app.NotificationManager;
import android.app.PendingIntent;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.PowerManager;
import android.os.PowerManager.WakeLock;
import android.support.v4.app.NotificationCompat;
import android.util.Log;

import com.google.android.gcm.GCMBaseIntentService;

public class GCMIntentService extends GCMBaseIntentService {

private static final String TAG = "===GCMIntentService===";
private static final String senderId = "559753615670";
String message;

public GCMIntentService() {
    super(senderId);
}

@Override
protected void onRegistered(Context arg0, String registrationId) {
    Intent registrationIntent = new Intent("com.google.android.c2dm.intent.REGISTER");
    // sets the app name in the intent
    registrationIntent.putExtra("app", PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, 0, new Intent(), 0));
    registrationIntent.putExtra("sender", senderId);
    startService(registrationIntent);
    Log.i(TAG, "Device registered: regId = " + registrationId);

}

@Override
protected void onUnregistered(Context arg0, String arg1) {
    Intent unregIntent = new Intent("com.google.android.c2dm.intent.UNREGISTER");
    unregIntent.putExtra("app", PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, 0, new Intent(), 0));
    startService(unregIntent);
    Log.i(TAG, "unregistered = " + arg1);
}

@Override
protected void onMessage(Context context, Intent intent) {
    intent.getStringExtra( "message" );

  Intent notificationIntent=new Intent(context,this.getApplicationContext().getClass());
  PowerManager pm = (PowerManager) context.getSystemService(Context.POWER_SERVICE);
  WakeLock wl = pm.newWakeLock(PowerManager.FULL_WAKE_LOCK | PowerManager.ACQUIRE_CAUSES_WAKEUP, "TAG");    
  wl.acquire();
 generateNotification(context, message, notificationIntent);



}

@SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
private static void generateNotification(Context context, String message, Intent   notificationIntent) {
     int icon = R.drawable.ic_launcher;
     long when = System.currentTimeMillis();


     NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager)
             context.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
    Notification notification = new Notification(icon, message, when);

    notificationManager.notify(0, notification);

     String title = context.getString(R.string.app_name);
     // set intent so it does not start a new activity
     notificationIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP |
             Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP);
     PendingIntent intent =PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0, notificationIntent,      PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
     notification.setLatestEventInfo(context, title, message, intent);
     notification.flags |= Notification.FLAG_AUTO_CANCEL;
     notificationManager.notify(0, notification);
    notification.defaults |= Notification.DEFAULT_SOUND;
   notification.defaults |= Notification.DEFAULT_VIBRATE;
  notification.ledARGB = 0xff00ff00;
 notification.ledOnMS = 300;
 notification.ledOffMS = 1000;
 notification.flags |= Notification.FLAG_SHOW_LIGHTS;
 }

@Override
protected void onError(Context arg0, String errorId) {
    Log.i(TAG, "Received error: " + errorId);
}

@Override
protected boolean onRecoverableError(Context context, String errorId) {
    return super.onRecoverableError(context, errorId);
}
}
```

SO can Anyone please help me with what's wrong OR missing in my Android code?

Comment: why r u use C2dm ? you should use GCM (Google Cloud Message)..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've got the regids and the API key the wrong way round in the PHP. It needs to be something like:

```
$registrationIDs = array(); 
/* fetch values */
 while ($stmt2->fetch()) {
   $regidOne =  $dev_i; // Filling the array with the regids
   $registrationIDs[] = $regidOne;
}
 $stmt2->close();
 $fields = array(
           'registration_ids' => $registrationIDs,
             'data' => array("message" => $message),
             'delay_while_idle'=> false,
             'collapse_key'=>"".$randomNum.""
            );
   $headers = array(
        'Authorization: key=' . $apiKey,
         'Content-Type: application/json'
         );

  // Open connection
   $ch = curl_init();
```

Comment: ok fine, but my main problem is in the Android that i dont know how to  implement it on Android